# RetroPie Wiimote throws Syntax error: unexpected ID?

Tags: retropie, bash

Why does this program (from RetroPie's Wiimote tutorial's `mywminput.sh`) throw a 'syntax error, unexpected ID'?

```
#!/bin/bash

ttl=30
alert="/home/pi/complete.oga"
fail="/home/pi/bark.oga"
begin_sound="/home/pi/robot-blip.wav"
end_sound="/home/pi/service-logout.oga"
mac="\([[:xdigit:]]\{2\}:\)\{5\}[[:xdigit:]]" # "00:" * 5 + "00"
device_file="/tmp/wiimote-scan"

function play {
    ogg123 $1 &> /dev/null &
}

function match {
    echo $1 | grep $2
}

function show {
    if [[ -n $DEBUG ]]
    then
        echo $1
    fi
}

# prevent scans from interfering with one another?
killall hcitool && sleep 5

if [[ `hcitool dev | grep hci` ]]
then
    play $begin_sound &> /dev/null &
    echo "Bluetooth detected, starting scan with ${ttl}s timeout..."

    timeout $ttl hcitool scan | while read device
    do
        show "found $device"

        if [[ `match "$device" "Nintendo"` ]]
        then
            show "matched Nintendo in $device"

            id=`echo $device | cut -d" " -f1`

            if [[ `match $id $mac` && \
                "$id"!="00:00:00:00:00:00" ]]
            then
                show "matched MAC in $id"

                echo -n "Detected Wiimote with ID: ${id}..."
                wminput -d -c /home/pi/mywminput $id &
                echo " registered."
                play $alert
            fi
        fi
    done

    play $end_sound
    echo "Scan complete."

    if [[ "$rebootWithoutWiimotes" == "1" && -z `pidof wminput` ]]
    then
        echo "No Wiimotes detected!  Restarting..."
        sudo reboot
    fi
else
    echo "Blue-tooth adapter not present!"
    play $fail
fi
```

Run with: `rebootWithoutWiimotes=0 /home/pi/bin/attachwii.sh`.
`attachwii.sh` is a script that calls the `mywminput.sh` seen above.
The error returned the details:

```
/home/pi/mywminput.sh: line 2, column 0:
syntax error, unexpected ID
```

This script is part of connecting a Nintendo Wii Wiimote

Comment: remove the space between `#!` and `/bin/bash` in line 1.

Comment: Sorry, a copy & paste error. Fixing it doesn't change anything though.

Comment: Did you copy&paste this from the site, or did you type this in yourself? I definitely see no issue around "line 2, column 0" as per the error message, unless you have some sort of a hidden character in this file on the empty line 2. Or perhaps you have MSDOS carriage returns in the file .... easy to see by opening the file with `nano` or `vi`.

Comment: How would I fix it?

Comment: Not sure if there's even an issue with MSDOS style CRs ... I think Linux just ignores those. But if there is a non-displaying character somewhere in there, that might cause an issue. However, I'm not saying that is the most likely issue - just the first thing I would look at.

Comment: If this is really a file format error, `dos2unix mywminput.sh` should solve the CR problem, and change the file to unix ascii again...

Answer (score 0):

So I just had this problem and solved it. Theres a simple typo in your mywminput file. Mine was WiiMote.A the correct code was Wiimote.A look for the type you have between lines 1 and 2

Comment: How can a typo be *between* lines 1 and 2? More importantly, there is nothing wrong with both these lines in the question: the first reads `#!/bin/bash` and the second is empty. Pretty sure there's no typo in there.